# Why value from a Material-UI Button is not being passed to the onClick event handler?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, material-ui, buttonclick

I am trying to pass a value from a Material-UI Button when it's clicked to it's click handler, but it's always showing `value` of `undefined`. Earlier when I was using a simple button, I was getting `value` but not after.

```
const categoryChangedHandler = (e) => {
        console.log("category choosed ========= " + e.target.value);
        setCategory(e.target.value);

    };
```

```
<Button className="CategoryButton" variant="outlined" color="primary"
                                value={category}
                                onClick={e => categoryChangedHandler(e)}
                                style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}
                            >
                                {category}
                            </Button>
```

and I am getting the result:

```
category choosed ========= undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `event.currentTarget.value` instead of `event.target.value`.

The text of a Material-UI `Button` is within a `<span>` inside a `<button>` element. When you click on the text, `event.target` will refer to the span element; whereas `event.currentTarget` will refer to the element with the event handler attached (i.e. the button element) that the click event bubbled up to.

Here's a simple working example:

```
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Button value="hello" onClick={(e) => console.log(e.currentTarget.value)}>
      Hello World
    </Button>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Button currentTarget]

Related answer:

- [Props not being passed down to Material UI button text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62760287/props-not-being-passed-down-to-material-ui-button-text/62760600#62760600)

Documentation:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget